# How to pull most recent (latest) docker image from DockerHub which contains commit hash as tag name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have gone through many posts but still not clear so posting my question here for better understanding.
I have 2 git repos. 1 for frontend and 1 for backend.
Developers write the code and push the code to the DockerHub once testing is done. Docker images have the `commit hash` as tag name (Image name = **username/myapp-fe:1906d8f**)
I am writing a Jenkins job with Ansible which will execute `docker-compose` file. `docker-compose`  will perform the following tasks

- Create docker network
- Pull and run the most recent image of frontend and backend from DockerHub.

I am unable to figure out the way to pull the latest docker image having `commit hash` as tag name?
Should I use docker's `Digest:sha256` in place of `commit hash` tag name and what benefits can I get from this replacement?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to perform something equivalent to `docker pull  username/myapp-fe:1906d8f` every time you run the job, do not use the SHA256 hash. Just use the tag itself.

If you use the Docker SHA256, you're specifying a specific image regardless of the tag, i.e. if there are multiple images with tag `1906d8f` you can specify an older one too: `docker pull username/myapp-fe@sha256:4ecb92a78f71a48c681a4d219a9ede869afd6dbedf27bc5dea44aa3e1a38ccea`. Notice how there's no tag in this way of referencing images.
The benefits of using this is that you're specifying a specific image instead of a floating tag - if that tag is updated with a faulty image, your pipeline can fail for apparently no reason - your code will not change, but your image does!